# SUM YTD calculation differ in SSRS compared to SSMS

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, mdx

I am trying to calculate the SUM & YTD but something goes wrong then moving the query to SSRS. I works fine in SSMS:

```
with member 
[Measures].[YTD] as 
aggregate(YTD([Dim Time].[Hierarchy].currentmember),[Measures].[Belopp])
, format_string = "currency"
select [Measures].[YTD] on columns,
[Dim Time].[Year].members on rows
from cube
```

[image: result SSMS]

I create this member in SSRS: 
[image: Query designer member]

When I view it in the report I get strange numbers. It´s like it´s making some extra summary or multiplication of the amount..

[image: Result SSRS]

Somebody seen anything like this before or maybe has a clue to what it could be?

It works fine when viewing with lowest level of granularity i.e. date. I can also make it workable with drill down from year to date.. but the correct numbers are only in the lowest level (date), at higher levels it sums up everything which is wrong, it should take the current YTD and display, how can I do that?